# joining on known values - teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

Table A has the value `'abc123'` 
Table B has the value `'abc123'`

I confirm this by

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a WHERE value='abc123'
and
SELECT * FROM tableB b WHERE value='abc123'
```

and both queries return results

however when i do:

```
select
    a.*
from
    tablea a
join
    tableb b
on trim(trailing from a.value) = trim(trailing from b.value)
```

nothing returns.

now the string I am dealing with in one of the these tables was imported over from unix and I made sure to strip out the whitespace, etc.

Comment: If you run a union query with that function and value from each table, what does it return?

Comment: it works.  What could be the difference between 'abc123' and 'abc123' that is stored in a teradata table?

Comment: Try running the UNION query again and include CHAR2HEXINT(value) and compare the values that are returned for differences. Can you share the table definitions?

Comment: Show the actual DDL definitions for both tables. I'm guessing that the character set or precision of the column `value` is different.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to comment but do you have null values in any of those columns?
if there are null try defaulting them and re run the query. I am guessing it to be Null handling issue.